# How to access last slide in bxSlider?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a bxSlider. I want that on reaching the last slide the next control should hide. I am using infiniteLoop to stop from looping back to the first slide. Using 'hideControlOnEnd' hides the previous control as well but I'd like to keep that. How to achieve this functionality? Is there any direct way to achieve this instead of writing long lines of code?

slider configuration -

```
$slider = $('.slider').bxSlider({

        pager: false,
        auto: true,
        moveSlides: 4, 
        minSlides: 4,
        maxSlides: 4,
        auto:false,
        infiniteLoop:false
})
```

I am trying something like -

```
function onSliderLoad (){
    $(document).on('click','.bx-next', function() {
        var current_slide = $slider.getCurrentSlide();
        //console.log(current_slide);
        var slide_count = $slider.getSlideCount();
        //console.log(slide_count);
        if (current_slide == slide_count){
        
            $('.bx-next').addClass('disabled');
        }
       });
    
}
```

I am calling this function on click of next-button. I have total of 6 slides. current_slide is returning me 1. The logic is not fitting correctly. Can anyone please suggest any solution?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : Found a better solution at -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122047/bxslider-get-first-and-last-slide

This helped me achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this...

```
onSliderLoad: function (){
    slider = $('.slider').bxSlider();
    var slide_count = slider.getSlideCount();
    var slide_curr = slider.getCurrentSlide();
}

if (slide_curr == slide_count-1){
    $('.bx-prev').addClass('disable');
}
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason .getSlideCount() and getCurrentSlide is giving me the same value at all times. I am calling the onSliderLoad function on click of next arrow as-
 slider = $('.slider').bxSlider(config);
        $( '.bx-next').click(function() {
            onSliderLoad ();
          });
        
function onSliderLoad (){
    var slide_count = slider.getSlideCount();
    var slide_curr = slider.getCurrentSlide();
    if (slide_curr == slide_count){
    $('.bx-next').addClass('disable');
}}

Comment: I have 6 slides. The next control should go away after reaching the 6th slide. If I move one slide at a time, getCurrentSlide should not return me 6. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have functions also for onSlideAfter and onSlideBefore ? if not, you should have them. In both functions you need to get the current slide and the whole counter and to update an insertCount(slide_curr, slide_count); function.

Comment: I am unaware of how to do that. I have included my code in the question. Could you please help out?